# iAd titanium white rectangle then disappears

Tags: ios, titanium, iad, titanium-mobile

Has any one encountered this already ? I put iAd with the code below in titanium studio and when the app loads in show a white rectangle which is where iAd should go thent it disappears ?

```
var iads = Ti.UI.iOS.createAdView({ width: 320, top: 100, backgroundColor: 'transparent', zIndex:200 });
t1 = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({bottom:0, duration:750});

iads.addEventListener('load', function(){
   iads.animate(t1);
});

Titanium.UI.currentWindow.add(iads);
```

Comment: Solved on it s own just by magic.. I don't know one day it works, the other it doesn't (in sim) I lost 2 days of work..

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change anything else (like switching to a different Titanium Mobile SDK) then this must have been something between you and Apple. Perhaps something going wrong between their sandbox and your simulator.